# Explicit casting in openCL

Tags: casting, opencl

I have a problem casting a float8 var into a double8 for sincos function in openCL. So I have tried the following:

```
float8 a,b,c;

a = convert_float8(sin(convert_double8(a))); // worked
a = convert_float8(sincos(convert_double8(b),convert_double8(&c))); // failed
```

and it would throw an openCL error saying fail to build program.  At first I thought sincos doesn't take in double8 type but it also works if I simply pass in a double8 var, however when I tried to cast a float8 into double8, it would just fail like the code above.

```
float8 a;
double8 b,c;

a = convert_float8(sincos((b),(&c))); //worked
```

Does anyone know why/how to cast it properly?

Thanks.

Comment: I am performing a precision analysis, which is why I need to convert float8 to double8 then back to float8, and thanks for the tip, I will accept some of the answers to my old questions.  But back on topic, do you have any ideas why it wouldn't work?  The example is contrived because that's exactly what I need to perform.

Comment: The code in the second code block does not compile for me. `sincos` requires two arguments, where you only provide one. Are you sure this code works?

Comment: oh sorry, thats a mistake when I typed it.  It should be:    a = convert_float8(sincos((b),(&c)));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first code example, `&c` is of type `float8*`, i.e. it's a memory address pointing to a `float8` value. You cannot use `convert_double` to convert this address to a pointer to `double8` (which is what `sincos` expects as its second argument in this context). I can't think of any sensible way in which this should work.

You have to explicitly create a temporary variable of the correct type:

```
float8 a,b,c;
double8 c_double;
a = convert_float8(sincos(convert_double8(b), &c_double));
c = convert_float8(c_double);
```

Comment: thanks, it should be a good enough fix for me to continue on the analysis